# On a particular matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

My question is as follows. Assume the equation,
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}V_1R_1 + V_2R_3 \\V_1R_3 + V_2R_2 \end{bmatrix},$$
where $V_1,V_2\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times \nu}$, $R_1,R_2,R_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{\nu \times \nu}$ and the following equality
$$ \Pi = \begin{bmatrix} V_1 \\ V_2 \end{bmatrix},$$
holds.

I would like to write $P$ as a matrix product involving $\Pi$ explicitly, say $M_1 \Pi M_2$ where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are suitable matrices. Any hint? Thanks!!!

Comment: I think $P=R \Pi$ works, where $R$ is a $2\nu \times 2\nu$ matrix given by $\begin{bmatrix}
    R_1 & R_3\\
    R_3 & R_2
  \end{bmatrix}$. If you want it with two matrices, then $P= R \Pi I_{2\nu}$.

Comment: @mkspk Thanks for the response. Note that $\Pi$ is actually a $2\times \nu$ matrix, so that the (usual) matrix product $P=R\Pi$ cannot be done.

Comment: Sorry, I thought $V_1$ and $V_2$ were column vectors.  As $P$ is also a $2\times \nu$ vector, you would need $M_1$ a $2\times 2$ matrix and $M_2$ a $\nu\times \nu$ matrix. I don't find easy choices of them that gets the result you want.